# Initialization of objects in the background

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, initialization

I need to initialize few objects, it can take a while so I want to do it in some background thread. I also want to display progressBar showing what is the progress of initialization.
What is the most elegant way to do it?

I was thinking about an interface:

```
interface ILoadable
{
    int Progress { get; }
    event EventHandler Loaded;
}
```

Comment: I think you'd also want a ProgressChanged event.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) directly?  It provides events for `DoWork`, `ProgressChanged`, and `RunWorkerCompleted`.

The advantage of this (or a thin wrapper over this) is that you automatically get the threading handled for you, properly, and it's very well tested.

If you want to make a wrapper around this, I'd actually recommend making yourself an abstract class that encapsulates the BackgroundWorker, and lets you provide `Action` delegates for the run operation.

Comment: That was quick. BackgroundWorker is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: +1 It also catches exceptions and marshals them back to the UI thread for you, very useful!